# Finding all combination of sum of tuple element from a list of tuple

Tags: python

I want to to generate a new_tuple_list that contains all possible sum of element 2, and element 3 from a given list of tuple. Element 2 and 3 will be int.

Input :

```
tuple_list = [('item1', 2, 20), ('item2', 3, 20), ('item3', 2, 50)]
```

Expected output:

```
new_tuple_list = [(5, 40),(7, 90), (5, 70)]
new_tuple_list = [(2 + 3, 20 +20), (2 + 3 +2 , 20 +20 + 50), (3 + 2,20 + 50)
```

Comment: This looks like homework, Can you please share what have you done to solve this?

Comment: I'm currently solving a problem similar to 0-1 knapback but the solution on the internet is way too complicated too understand at beginner level so  I'm just trying to figure. another way around.

Comment: this is not the way to solve knapsack problem

Comment: similar but not 0-1 kapsack

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is the function for this job.
You can use it as

```
from itertools import combinations
new_tuple_list = []
for k in range(2, len(tuple_list)+1):
    for combination in combinations(tuple_list, k):
        e1, e2 = 0, 0
        for element in combination:
            text, int1, int2 = element
            e1 += int1
            e2 += int2
        new_tuple_list.append((e1, e2))
```

for loop was used for demonstration purposes, but you could also use list comprehension or `map()` if you want.

Notice that this results in `new_tuple_list` having 4 elements, including (4, 70) for adding 'item1' and 'item3'.  I hope this is the intended behavior.